# Fisher-Yates Shuffle

Tags: javascript, algorithm, shuffle

This is a cut-and-dried Fisher-Yates implementation. As not typically a JS developer, I've tried to incorporate as many best practices as I can. I would appreciate any input as to make it conform to more best practices and continue to be maintainable.

```
(function fisherYates () {

    "use strict";

    var shuffle = function shuffle (array) {

        var beginningIndex = 0,
            currentIndex = array.length,
            indexDecrement = 1,
            randomIndex = 0,
            temporaryValue = 0;

        // While elements remain to be shuffled...
        while (currentIndex !== beginningIndex) {

            // Pick an element from the remaining elements...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= indexDecrement;

            // Swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;

        }

        return array;

    };

    return shuffle;

}());
```

Comment: Minor point - having indexDecrement as a variable makes it look like it could change.  IMO, "currentIndex--" is clear enough on its own, but if you did want it named it should be const.

Comment: @Errorsatz I agree - was just trying to shush the linter :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The docs on "use strict" are vague but I'm not entirely sure putting it inside a function makes it apply to the function definition.
- `var shuffle = function shuffle (array) {` seems unnecessarily redundant. I would just use `function shuffle (array) {`
- Use `const` and `let` instead of `var` (unless you're trying to support older browsers)
- It doesn't make sense to initialize `randomIndex` or `temporaryValue`.
- I would write `while (currentIndex > beginningIndex) {` especially if the `indexDecrement` could be something other than `1`. Actually I would prefer a `for` loop though its arguable given the way your loop is structured.
- I would use destructuring assignment to swap values:

  ```
  [ array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex] ] = [ array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex] ];
  ```
- If you use `const` or `let` you can move the definition of `randomIndex` and `temporaryValue` inside the loop block.
- You return the `shuffle` function but your IIFE doesn't assign it anywhere. Apart from the fact that this seems unnecessarily complex I wonder if this even works?

Answer (score 0):

I have incorporated most of [Marc Rohloff](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/130137/marc-rohloff)'s [points](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/204169/6172) (with the notable exception of the last -- I am currently letting [Will It Shuffle?](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html) work with the result of the IIFE), while minimizing hacking off the linter and have come up with this:

```
/* eslint-env es6 */
/* eslint no-magic-numbers: ["error", { "ignore": [1] }] */
/* eslint one-var: ["error", "consecutive"] */
(function fisherYates () {

    const shuffle = function shuffle (array) {

        let currentIndex = array.length;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (currentIndex) {

            // Pick a remaining element...
            const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);

            currentIndex -= 1;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            [
                array[currentIndex],
                array[randomIndex]
            ] = [
                array[randomIndex],
                array[currentIndex]
            ];

        }

        return array;

    };

    return shuffle;

}());
```